# Dependency Injection vb.net using unity

Tags: .net, vb.net, dependency-injection

I am trying to implement Dependency injection using unity Container in vb.net

when i do call the resolve method i get a resolutionFaieldException error

**Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Test.EmailSending", name = "PDFEmailSender".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.**

```
Module Module1

Private iemail As IErrorEmail

Sub Main()

    'Dim email As New Test.EmailSending(iemail)
    'email.Email()
    Dim unity As UnityContainer = New UnityContainer
    unity.RegisterType(Of IErrorEmail, SQLErrorEmail)("SQLErrorEmail")
    unity.RegisterType(Of IErrorEmail, GenericEmail)("GenericEmail")
    unity.RegisterType(Of IErrorEmail, Emailsending)("Emailsending")
    Dim email1 = unity.Resolve(Of EmailSending)("SQLErrorEmail")
    email1.Email()
End Sub



End Module
```

The Interface is simple Error email Interface

```
Namespace InterfaceError
Public Interface IErrorEmail
    Function ErrorEmail() As Boolean
End Interface
End Namespace
```

I have added two types of email classes which implement the Ierror interface

```
Imports InterfaceSender.InterfaceError
Public Class SQLErrorEmail
    Implements IErrorEmail
    Private _SenderEmail As IErrorEmail
    Public Sub New(SQLErrorEmail As IErrorEmail)
        _SenderEmail = SQLErrorEmail
    End Sub
    Public Function ErrorEmail() As Boolean Implements IErrorEmail.ErrorEmail
        Dim isemailed As Boolean = False
        Try
            Email()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return isemailed
    End Function
    Public Shared Sub Email()
        Console.WriteLine("SQL Error Email")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The above SQL error Class implements the ErrorEmail function  and writes to console that it is a SQL error email.

```
    Imports InterfaceSender.InterfaceError
Public Class GenericEmail
    Implements IerrorEmail
    Private _SenderEmail As IErrorEmail
    Public Sub New(GenericEmail As IErrorEmail)
        _SenderEmail = GenericEmail
    End Sub
    Public Function SendEmail() As Boolean Implements IErrorEmail.ErrorEmail
        Dim isemailed As Boolean = False
        Try
            Email()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Return isemailed
    End Function
    Public Shared Sub Email()
        Console.WriteLine("Generic Error Email")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The above class implements the generic error which inherits the Ierror interface and when the email method is called it outputs an Genric output email to a console.

```
    Imports Method.GenericEmail
Imports Method.SQLErrorEmail
Imports InterfaceSender.InterfaceError
Public Class EmailSending
    Private _Isender As IErrorEmail
    Public Sub New(ByVal Email As IErrorEmail)
        MyBase.New()
        _Isender = Email
    End Sub
    Public Sub EmailSendingLogic()
        Dim type As String = "SQL"
        If type = "SQL" Then
            Method.SQLErrorEmail.Email()
        ElseIf type = "Generic" Then
            Method.GenericEmail.Email()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you register `EmailSending` itself too? Because it isn't registered in the code above

Comment: no i did not i will try

Comment: What is the object graph that you are trying to create? Which implementation of `IErrorEmail` do you want to inject into `EmailSending`? Can you explain more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: In the class emailsending i have method EmailSendingLogic which decides the logic whether send an SQL error or Generic error.   In the Module 1 class i don't want to call generic or sql error . For the time being i have have SQLErrorEmail .   I don't know what you mean by object graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you are trying to create a class (`EmailSending`) that knows which `IErrorEmail` to use depending on some logic.

First, you don't have to inject `IErrorEmail` into the constructors of `GenericEmail` and `SQLErrorEmail`. Why are you doing this?

Here is how I see these two classes should look like:

```
Public Class SQLErrorEmail
    Implements IErrorEmail
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    Public Function ErrorEmail() As Boolean Implements IErrorEmail.ErrorEmail
        Console.WriteLine("SQL Error Email")
        Return True
    End Function

End Class


Public Class GenericEmail
    Implements IErrorEmail

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    Public Function SendEmail() As Boolean Implements IErrorEmail.ErrorEmail
        Console.WriteLine("Generic Error Email")
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, since the `EmailSending` class needs to use both email senders (`GenericEmail` and `SQLErrorEmail`), you should inject two `IErrorEmail` dependencies into it like this:

```
Public Class EmailSending
    Private ReadOnly m_GenericSender As IErrorEmail
    Private ReadOnly m_SqlSender As IErrorEmail
    Public Sub New(generic_sender As IErrorEmail, sql_sender As IErrorEmail)
        m_GenericSender = generic_sender
        m_SqlSender = sql_sender
    End Sub

    Public Sub EmailSendingLogic()
        Dim type As String = "SQL"
        If type = "SQL" Then
            m_SqlSender.ErrorEmail()
        ElseIf type = "Generic" Then
            m_GenericSender.ErrorEmail()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Finally, here is how you would register your object graph via unity:

```
Dim unity As UnityContainer = New UnityContainer
unity.RegisterType(Of IErrorEmail, SQLErrorEmail)("SQLErrorEmail")
unity.RegisterType(Of IErrorEmail, GenericEmail)("GenericEmail")
unity.RegisterType(Of EmailSending)(
    New InjectionConstructor(
        New ResolvedParameter(Of IErrorEmail)("GenericEmail"),
        New ResolvedParameter(Of IErrorEmail)("SQLErrorEmail")))
```

And here is how you would resolve and use your `EmailSending`:

```
Dim email1 = unity.Resolve(Of EmailSending)()

email1.EmailSendingLogic()
```

Another way to do this (which I think is better in terms of design), is to create an [abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) that creates the appropriate `IErrorEmail` implementation based on some logic (e.g. type). Here is an example:

```
Public Interface IErrorEmailFactory
    Function Create(type As String) As IErrorEmail
End Interface

Public Class ErrorEmailFactory
    Implements IErrorEmailFactory

    Public Function Create(type As String) As IErrorEmail Implements IErrorEmailFactory.Create
        If type = "SQL" Then
            Return New SQLErrorEmail()
        ElseIf type = "Generic" Then
            Return New GenericEmail()
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

And then, you would inject a `IErrorEmailFactory` into `EmailSending` like this:

```
Public Class EmailSending
    Private ReadOnly m_Factory As IErrorEmailFactory

    Public Sub New(factory As IErrorEmailFactory)
        m_Factory = factory
    End Sub

    Public Sub EmailSendingLogic()
        Dim type As String = "SQL"

        Dim error_email = m_Factory.Create(type)

        error_email.ErrorEmail()

    End Sub
End Class
```

And then you would register it and use it like this:

```
Dim unity As UnityContainer = New UnityContainer

unity.RegisterType(Of IErrorEmailFactory, ErrorEmailFactory)()

Dim email1 = unity.Resolve(Of EmailSending)()

email1.EmailSendingLogic()
```

Comment: You are a life saver !!!!.  Great explanation. Is the ierrorEmail interface created by the RegisterType or the resolve method of unity.

Comment: `RegisterType` simply creates a mapping between an interface and a class (there are other types of mappings too). `Resolve` is used to actually create the object (or object graph). I hope I understood your question correctly.